# How Do I Manipulate a Global Array Within a Function? (C++)

Tags: c++, variables, global

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool life[82][82][26];

int cn(int row, int col, int g)
{
int count = 0;
for(int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++)
{
        for(int c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++)
        {
            if((r == row) && (c = col))
                continue;
            else if(life[r][c][g] == true)
                count++;
            else
                continue;
        }
}
return (count);
}

int main(){

ifstream fin("start.dat");
ofstream fout("boards.txt");

int row, col, g, a, b, c, i;

for(row = 0; row < 82; row++)
    for(col = 0; col < 82; col++)
        for(g = 0; g < 26; g++)
            life[row][col][g] = false;

fin >> a >> b >> c;
for(i = 1; i <= a; i++)
{
    life[b][c][0] = true;
    fin >> b >> c;
}

fout << cn(40, 40, 0);



return 0;}
```

I'm making [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).

My problem (I think) is that I'm doing something wrong with my "cn" (count_neighbors) function. It's supposed to count all of the "alive" (true) cells around the cell in question, but when I run the program, nothing comes out. This makes me think that either the "life[][][]" array is somehow messed up, or the loop is written incorrectly. I literally get a blinking cursor when I run this program.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that `if((r == row) && (c = col))` should have been `if((r == row) && (c == col))`?

Comment: Dang, I don't even think the compiler would complain in this case, either.

Comment: It is valid to assign the value of c to col. The boolean expression will then evaluate to true if the integer is 1 I think.

Comment: Not 0 to be more precise, but my point was that the common warning is typically subdued by adding redundant parentheses around the assignment, and indeed these are redundant. For example, `if (c = col)` would produce a warning and `if ((c = col))` would not. I don't know for sure what would result of this given the same warning and compiler configuration.

Comment: I know we just met, but I think I might be in love with you.